# How do I show this is a solution for this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Consider that

$$E(t,x)=\dfrac{H(t)}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-|x|^2/4t}.$$

I want to show that $E_t - E_{xx} = \delta(t)\delta(x)$. This means that we need to show that if $\phi\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is a test-function, then

$$(E_t-E_{xx},\phi)=(\delta(t)\delta(x),\phi)=\phi(0,0).$$

Now, what I know is that

$$(E_t,\phi)=-(E(t,x),\phi_t)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-|x|^2/4t}\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}(t,x) dtdx.$$

While we have that

$$(E_{xx},\phi)=(E,\phi_{xx})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-|x|^2/4t}\dfrac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}(t,x)dtdx.$$

Now I have no idea on how to procede with this. I mean, we have the derivatives of $\phi$ inside which might depend on the two variables. And we have no information about $\phi$, we just know it is a test function.

I've tried integration by parts but I didn't get very far. How can these integrals be solved in order to show that the result is just $\phi(0,0)$?

I believe there's some easy way, but I can't find it. The integration by parts just got me that

$$E_t-E_{xx} = \dfrac{H(t)e^{-x^2/4t}}{16\pi t^3}(x^2(2+\sqrt{\pi t} - 4t(1+\sqrt{\pi t})),$$

but this is not of much help. It is certainly not obvious that when we integrate $\phi$ against this we have $\phi(0,0)$. I already tried everything but it didn't work

Comment: Assuming that $H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function, you just have to start taking derivatives as you normally would, but with the caveat that $H'(t) = \delta(t)$ as distributions. I'm not sure how you get a $\delta(x)$, though, seeing as there's no $H(x)$.

Comment: Properly integrate by parts.